# why always predict same class for all input

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets as ds

iris = ds.load_iris()
x = iris.data
y1 = iris.target

x = x / x.max()
y1 = np.matrix(y1)
np.random.seed(1)
y = np.zeros((y1.size, y1.max() + 1))
y[np.arange(y1.size), y1] = 1

class NeuralNetwork(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.inputSize = 4
        self.outputSize = 3
        self.hiddenSize = 5

        self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputSize, self.hiddenSize) * 0.01
        self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenSize, self.outputSize) * 0.01
        self.b1 = np.random.randn(1, self.hiddenSize)
        self.b2 = np.random.randn(1, self.outputSize)

    def forward(self, x):
        self.z = np.dot(x, self.W1) + self.b1
        self.z2 = self.sigmoid(self.z)
        self.z3 = np.dot(self.z2, self.W2) + self.b2
        o = self.sigmoid(self.z3)
        return o

    def sigmoid(self, s):

        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-s))

    def sigmoidPrime(self, s):

        return s * (1 - s)

    def backward(self, x, y, o):
        l = 0.2
        self.dz2 = y - o
        self.dw2 = (1 / 150 * self.dz2.T.dot(self.z)).T

        self.db2 = 1 / 150 * np.sum(self.dz2, axis=0).reshape(1, 3)

        self.dz1 = 1 / 150 * self.W2.dot(self.dz2.T).T * self.sigmoidPrime(self.z)

        self.dw1 = (1 / 150 * self.dz1.T.dot(x)).T

        self.db1 = 1 / 150 * np.sum(self.dz1, axis=0).reshape(1, 5)

        self.W1 = self.W1 - l * self.dw1

        self.W2 = self.W2 - l * self.dw2

        self.b1 = self.b1 - l * self.db1

        self.b2 = self.b2 - l * self.db2

    def train(self, x, y):
        o = self.forward(x)
        self.backward(x, y, o)
```

when I run this code it predicts always same class
but when I change backward function to this one:

```
def backward(self, x, y, o):
    self.o_error = y - o
    self.o_delta = self.o_error * self.sigmoidPrime(o)
    self.z2_error = self.o_delta.dot(self.W2.T)
    self.z2_delta = self.z2_error * self.sigmoidPrime(self.z2)
    self.W1 += x.T.dot(self.z2_delta)
    self.W2 += self.z2.T.dot(self.o_delta)
```

It predicts correctly. Why first function doesn't work correctly (backward)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem with adjusting learning rate and adding regularization and some optimization